# Best practice for using slightly modifying module from CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm using DBI and DBD::SQLite, and now I'd like to use the R*Tree feature of SQLite.  Since this feature is not compiled by DBD::SQLite by default, I have to add a `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1` to the `@CC_DEFINE` variable in DBD::SQLite's Makefile.PL.  If I do a 'perl Makefile.PL && make && make install', everything works fine locally on my machine, but this ultimately needs to be deployable/distributable to end users.

What should I do in a case like this? Should I copy the source, grep the source, and create a DBD::SQLite::WithRTree?  Create a private version of DBD::SQLite 1.31.1 (Where 1.31 is the current version of DBD::SQLite)?  Perhaps a better way altogether?

All other distributions in the project are deployed/distributed via a non-public CPAN::Mini mirror + CPAN::Mini::Inject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have to add a '-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1' to the @CC_DEFINE variable in DBD::SQLite's Makefile.PL

You're doing this wrong, `perl Makefile.PL DEFINE='-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1'` works. This is documented in [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#DEFINE). Now that you know that, a simple solution involving [Distroprefs](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#Configuration_for_individual_distributions_(Distroprefs)) will likely fall in place.

Answer (score 3):

For similar problems, I have installed the modified distribution in a separate directory (without changing any module names), and using `use lib qw(the/special/directory)` or setting `$PERL5LIB` for scripts that need to use the enhanced module.

Tweaking the name of the module would also do the job, but that sound like a lot more work to make and test.

Comment: And keeping careful record of what you changed

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
cpan
o conf makepl_arg "DEFINE='-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1'"
o conf commit
```

CPAN will then permanently add that DEFINE to the front of all your Makefile.PL calls.

So, it *should* just be

```
cpan DBD::SQLite
```

And your makefile options should get stuffed onto your compile lines